# f : N → R or f : N → Z or both?

Tags: functions

True or false? The following functions are bijective and correctly defined.

1. $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ and $f(n) = n/2$ if $n$ is even and, $-(n+1)/2$ if $n$ is odd
2. $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ and $f(n) = n/2$ if $n$ is even and, $-(n+1)/2$ if $n$ is odd

Since both statements are practically the same, I assume one will be true and the other false. I also know for a fact that both are bijective. As such, I think that statement 1) is false because it isn't correctly defined (it should be f : N → R like statement 2). Am I right? If so, how to prove that statement 1) isn't correctly defined? Or are both statements true because Z is included in R?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Why are both bijective?  Which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ gives the real number $\pi$, for example?

Comment: To the question in your title: Both. To the question in the beginning of the text: (2) is bijective and not (1), but both are correctly defined. To the first sentence in your second paragraph: they are not practically the same.

Comment: To use dinosaur language, as other responses have indicated, just because a function is *one-to-one*, that does not automatically imply that the function is also *onto*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions are correctly defined. This is because the function in the first example can return any real number. The second function must only return integers, but this is ensured.

In order for a function to be bijective, it needs to be surjective, that is, the function must achieve every element from the destination set. But since the first one only takes in natural numbers, it can never achieve $\pi$ or $e$  or $\sqrt2$. Hence, it is not bijective.

The second function gets to all non-negative integers via even natural numbers (including $0$). And it gets to all negative integers via odd natural numbers, thus it is surjective. But that's not all! The function needs to also be injective to be bijective. Injectivity means distinctive mapping. In other words, $f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2}) => x_{1} = x_{2}$. It is true, thus the second example is a bijective function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now. How can I mathematically prove that the first function is not surjective? Sorry if it's a dumb question. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: You only need to prove that it never arrives at $\sqrt2$, right? So, notice that it is irrational. But if you plug in a natural number for $n$, as is required, the function will always give you a rational number, which completes the proof.

Answer (score 4):

In order for the function to be bijective, you certainly need it to be surjective.

The first function is surjective if for every $y\in \mathbb R$ you can find $x\in\mathbb N$ with $y=f(x)$.

The second function is surjective if for every $y\in \mathbb Z$ you can find $x\in\mathbb N$ with $y=f(x)$.

Do you see the  difference?